# Cannot POST / in node / express js, problem with form

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to send data from a form and it must be received on a route with a GET method. However, it does not work. I get the following:

> Cannot POST / dashboard

---

**HTML**

```html
<form action="dashboard" method="get" class="uk-grid-small" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@s">
        <input
            class="uk-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter the keyword"
            name="keyword"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@s">
        <select class="uk-select">
            <option>Anywhere</option>
            <option>España</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@s">
        <select class="uk-select">
            <option>Any language</option>
            <option>Spanish</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@s">
        <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Node.js/Express**

```
app.get('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {
    var pal = req.body.keyword
    console.log(req.body.keyword)
})
```

Comment: Shooting from the hip here, but maybe you want `app.post('/dashboard' ... )` instead of `app.get`?

Comment: Not, i need get.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot slash in action="/dashboard", and use req.query.keyword to get your data

```
<form action="/dashboard" method="get" class="uk-grid-small" uk-grid>

            <div class="uk-width-1-4@s">
                <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter the keyword" name="keyword">
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-1-4@s">
       <select class="uk-select">
           <option>Anywhere</option>
           <option>España</option>
       </select>

            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-1-4@s">
              <select class="uk-select">
                  <option>Any language</option>
                  <option>Spanish</option>
              </select>
                      </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-1-4@s">

 <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Search</button>
```

```
app.get('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {
   var pal = req.query.keyword;
   console.log(req.query.keyword);
});
```

Comment: Instead of req.body.keywork, you have to use req.query.keywork because you have used GET

Comment: Worked with it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Instead of req.body.keywork, you have to use req.query.keywork because you have used GET that @IDIRSamir mentioned.

```
app.get('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {
   var pal = req.query.keyword;
   console.log(req.query.keyword);
});
```

Comment: Worked with it.